# Root cause of flickering problems of web-based mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-3, jqtouch, zepto

I just create a simple [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org) app based on [jqTouch](http://jqtjs.com) und [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com).

The app has **3 pages**, one contains one **form of 4 controls**, the other pages **3 navigational elements and a few lines of text**.

Using the [jqTouch's](http://jqtjs.com) `apple` and `jqtouch` themes, the app shows **enormous amounts of flickering**. During a page transition, certain parts of the screen render black.

jqTouch's `innsbruck` theme has a **bit less flickering**, but still is by no means ready to production.

The test-app **doesn't use add-on javaScript**. All **navigation is done using #pageName** links. Thus, user supplied JavaScript might be no problem here.

Interestingly: If I open the [jqTouch demos](http://jqtjs.com/preview/demos/main/index.html#home) using the built-in mobile browser, these execute with **much less flickering**.

**Since the app is very simple - it not even uses additional styles or images -, I wonder what the root cause of these rendering problems is.**

Tested using this environment:

- Apache Cordova 3.0.5
- Android 4.4.2
- Nexus 7

**Appcelerator Titanium - Poor too**

Additionally, I gave [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com) a try using the [rss example](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/samples/rss). Using the test device, the performance was poor too.

Appcelerator claims to compile to native. But due to poor performance, I guess they compile to WebViews too.

**Do they? Or does [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com) compiles views and controllers to pure JavaCode?**

**Next try**

Next, I'm going to give [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the native browser will be more efficient than your Cordova app.
Cordova uses a webview, which is less powerfull.

That aside, the flickering issue you're seeing is fixable by rendering the element on the GPU.
Via CSS you can specify :

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

or

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

*With needed vendor prefixes.*

This will force your element to be rendered by the GPU. And will fix your flickering issue, but you must target your faulty element.

Comment: So if I would pack all the stuff in a mobile-local web server and launch the system browser, I probably would get better performance? If I understand your A correctly, rendering the 'artificial' UI in the WebKit WebView is the primary problem? At least on iOS, shouldn't WebKit of Cordova be as fast/slow as Safari?

Comment: If the CSS would skip all the fade-in / dissolve animation stuff, would the result render better?

Comment: You'll have the flickering problem everywhere, Webview and browser. It's not performance related. It's a rendering problem, which you can fix, with this CSS. No need to skip animation stuff if it's not hurting the performances. A phone/tablet can handle that just fine.

Comment: As an update following iOS8's announcement, the difference between Webviews and native Safari won't be a problem anymore : http://9to5mac.com/2014/06/03/ios-8-webkit-changes-finally-allow-all-apps-to-have-the-same-performance-as-safari/